# Skip First consecutive records which has same values, then stop

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table scenario

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
| userd_id | user_value |    user_datetime    | i_want_to_select |
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
|        1 |          1 | 2020-01-31 12:13:14 |                  |
|        2 |          1 | 2020-01-30 12:13:14 |                  |
|        3 |          1 | 2020-01-29 12:13:14 |                  |
|        4 |          2 | 2020-01-28 12:13:14 |                  |
|        5 |          2 | 2020-01-27 12:13:14 |                  |
|        6 |          3 | 2020-01-20 12:13:14 |                  |
|        7 |          1 | 2020-01-19 12:13:14 | this             |
|        8 |          1 | 2020-01-18 12:13:14 | this             |
|        9 |          1 | 2020-01-17 12:13:14 | this             |
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

The need is to **skip** those consecutive values, **only IF first element is 1,** ​​and stop as soon as the value is different

I do it in PHP code, but I want to avoid weighing down the PHP processor and the garbage collector

```
foreach ($rows as &$row){
   if($row['user_value'] === 1){
       unset($row); // remove my row
   } else {
      break; // at the first different value, stop
   }
}

unset($row);
$rows = array_values($rows) //reset the array index/key
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.user_datetime >= (select min(t2.user_datetime)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                               t2.user_value <> 1
                        );
```

You can also use window functions, for instance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min( case when t.user_value <> 1 then t user_datetime) over (partition by t.user_id) as min_not1_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where user_datetime >= min_not1_datetime;
```

Comment: I'll try the first one

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Is the first one, but with ">" sign instead of "<" because I want to "exclude/skip" and not "select" the first results, and was my fault, I correct the question. 
I wrote "I want to select" instead of "I want to skip", but the PHP example was right